# Which technique has the lowest memory consumption: global variables or function arguments?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, duplicate-data

The program I'm coding now makes a pretty huge list of data items.

Now, I can make this list to be global (make available for other functions in other modules) and can be used in all other modules.  Or, I can also pass them as a function arguments for the functions in the modules.

Note that, this huge array I'm talking about is not going to get modified in the functions in other modules, they just read data and use it for calculations and data stats etc.

So, of the two methods which has least memory consumption?

If by passing into the functions, if the language makes a local duplicates of the huge list even if the functions doesn't modify it .. that'll be doubling of the memory consumption which is not good thing. If this happens, I can make it global and use it. I got this doubt on memory management of python because when I once wrote a toy language, I included this particular issue.. i.e the argument data gets duplicated only if its edited .. else, it'll always be pointed to the original data.

Comment: http://arctrix.com/nas/python/gc/  -- For further reference, I found this very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, there's no such thing as a 'global' variable in Python (in the sense that it's automatically available to all modules).

Secondly, Python doesn't duplicate objects when passing to a function. Python variables are really just names that point to objects - when you pass a variable to a function, all that happens is that the function creates a new name that points to the original object. You can read or modify the contents of that object without any copies being made. (Note that if you rebind the name to a different object, the original reference is not changed.)

Answer (score 2):

The two methods will have the same memory footprint. In python using global variable is considered bad practice, so you should avoid it.

Now to use python you need to understand its object semantics. But a simple example would be:

```
def modify(aList):
    aList[1] = 18

a = [1, 2, 3]
modify(a)
print a # [1, 18, 3]
b = a
b[2] = 12
print a [1, 18, 12]
print a is b # true
```

inside modify, the aList refers to the same object than a. Same with b. Every time you modify the element of the list using any label pointing to it, the object is modified. Function calling only pass the labels, not the objects.

`a is b` allows you to test whether the a and b labels refer to the the object.

Answer (score 1):

Python variables are references, so pass the name of the array - although strictly you should call it a list (it's what arrays are called in Python).  However, I'm disturbed by your wording which implies that you can have it global AND pass it as a parameter.  Do one thing or the other.  If it is a global then use it as a global, don't mix the two methods (sorry if I misunderstood).

For garbage collection, a good start would be to look at the standard library documentation for the `gc` module.

There is a bit about memory management in the Python/C API standard doc.  Search for "memory Management".

Comment: Sorry. My apologies, it's a list.

Comment: I actually meant that there're two methods, : one is the usage of the global variable or pass as an argument.